# Add Static Text to DynamicJasper

Tags: java, dynamic-jasper

I am using DynamicJasper to create a report. The code I have written for the same creates a table and fills it with the collection I pass to it.

Now I want to add some static text on top the table. How can I do that?

The code I have written is as follows:

```
private DynamicReport getReport(Style headerStyle, Style detailTextStyle, Style detailNumStyle) throws ColumnBuilderException, ClassNotFoundException {

            DynamicReportBuilder report=new DynamicReportBuilder();

            AbstractColumn columnName = createColumn("pluginName", String.class,"Plugin Name", 30, headerStyle, detailTextStyle);        
            AbstractColumn columnSalary = createColumn("displayName", String.class,"Display Name", 30, headerStyle, detailNumStyle);
            AbstractColumn columnCommission = createColumn("pluginDescription", String.class,"Plugin Description", 30, headerStyle, detailNumStyle);
            report.addColumn(columnName).addColumn(columnSalary).addColumn(columnCommission);

            StyleBuilder titleStyle=new StyleBuilder(true);
            titleStyle.setHorizontalAlign(HorizontalAlign.CENTER);
            titleStyle.setFont(new Font(20, Font._FONT_GEORGIA, true));

            StyleBuilder subTitleStyle=new StyleBuilder(true);
            subTitleStyle.setHorizontalAlign(HorizontalAlign.CENTER);
            subTitleStyle.setFont(new Font(Font.MEDIUM, Font._FONT_GEORGIA, true));

            report.setTitle("Plugin Output Report");
            report.setTitleStyle(titleStyle.build());
            report.setSubtitle("Commission received by Employee");
            report.setSubtitleStyle(subTitleStyle.build());
            report.setUseFullPageWidth(true);
            return report.build();
        }
```

The report that gets created looks like this

[image]

And I want some static text on top of this table. Please help

Comment: where exactly do you need the text? looks like a subtitle would do the trick but you've got one defined already but it's not showing?

Answer (score 1):

DynamicJasper AutoText might be helpful..

Check http://dynamicjasper.com/2010/10/06/how-to-create-autotext-ie-page-xy-out-of-the-box/

```
AutoText title = new AutoText("Plugin Output Report"),
AutoText.POSITION_HEADER,
HorizontalBandAlignment.CENTER);
title.setWidth(new Integer(500));
report.addAutoText(title);
```